# Hi.. I am using latex for my thesis, I need some help in titles pages

Tags: table-of-contents

First i need to add in table of content, tables of figures and list of tables the title and page as i circle in picture which show my need..[image]

```
\documentclass{UnimasThesis}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage[os=win]{menukeys}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[]{algorithm2e}
%\usepackage{enumerate}



\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=[LaTeX]TeX,columns=fullflexible,
basicstyle=\ttfamily,texcsstyle=*\bfseries\color{NavyBlue},
commentstyle=\itshape\color{PaleVioletRed4},
frame=single,framesep=6pt,
framexleftmargin=6pt,framexrightmargin=6pt,
xleftmargin=12pt,xrightmargin=12pt,
breaklines=true,breakatwhitespace=true}


\title{Automatic Segmentation of Cardiac Magnetic Resonance Images for Oedema Assessment}
\author{\textbf{Amajd Khan}}
\faculty{Faculty of Computer Science and Information Technology}
\facultyColour{6c7a8c} %% 6-digit RGB hexadecimal code 
\submissionyear{\textbf{2017}}
\degreetype{\textbf{Doctor of Philosophy}}

% If using APA bibliography style

\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite} 
\bibliographystyle{apacite}



%\usepackage{natbib}

%\bibliographystyle{apalike}



\newgeometry{top=3cm, bottom=3.00cm, right=2.5cm, left=2.5cm}

%\usepackage{etoolbox} % "lipsum" for filler text
%\makeatletter

\makeatletter



\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    %%%%\vspace*{50\p@}% %%% removed!
    {\parindent \z@ \Large
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \centering \Large\bfseries \MakeUppercase{\@chapapp}\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 3\p@
        \fi
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \centering
        \Large \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
}}
%\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
%  %%%%%\vspace*{50\p@}% %%% removed!
%  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
%    \normalfont
%    \interlinepenalty\@M
%    \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
%    \vskip 40\p@
%  }}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\frontmatter

\newpage~
\thispagestyle{empty}
{\centering {Automatic Segmentation of Cardiac Magnetic Resonance Images for Oedema Assessment} \par}
\vspace{4.7cm}
{\centering Amjad Khan\par}
\vspace{4.7cm}
{\centering A thesis submitted \\
    in fulfillment of the requirements for the degree of \\
    Doctor of Philosophy\par}

\vspace{5.5cm}
{\centering Faculty of Computer Sciences and Information Technology\\
    UNIVERSITI MALAYSIA SARAWAK\\ 
    2017\par}


% List of conformation may be prepared as in confirmation.tex
%\input{confirmation}
% List of declaration may be prepared as in confirmation.tex
\input{declaration}

% Acknowledgements from ack.tex
\input{ack}



% English abstract from abstract-en.tex
\input{abstract-en}

% Malay Abstract from abstrak-ms.tex
%\input{ABSTRAK}




%\input{abstract-mal}
% Malay Abstract from abstrak-ms.tex
\input{abstrak-ms}





% LIST OF TABLE 
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

% List of Symbols may be prepared as in symbols.tex
\input{symbols}

\mainmatter
% Each chapter from a separate file
\input{chap1-Introduction}
\input{chap2-literature}
\input{chap3-NEW}
\input{chap4-contoursegmentation}
\input{chap5-assessment}
\input{chap6-oedema}
\input{chap7-conclusion}
%\appendix
%\input{app-Guidelines}
%\input{app-code}
%\input{app-results}


% references are listed in refs.bib
\bibliography{refs}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello can any one help

Comment: I am trying but can't find your thesis template. You probably have a UnimasThesis.cls in your folder. If you help us by providing a link to that we may find the way to help you.

Comment: @koleygr    please  find the attached cls file

Comment: The template was created to follow thevlayout rules of this specific university. Don't bother with any changes.

Comment: Sorry... I tried to compile but I have no luck. When you adding code you have to select all the code and then to press the `{}` button (for your answer -please edit-). Also it would be better to edit your question and add the template of the answer because now your question seems to have an answer and you have lower possibilities to be vewed.

Comment: Not your fault, of course, but when I see such requirement I imagine the faculty members as funny people who should be told what's the title and what's the page number, because they can't distinguish them without some help.

Comment: I still not solved this problem plz anyone help